# Strange inheritance during the override of a method

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, jython-2.7

I'm developing different objects that are inherited from each other.
 At one point I noticed that the code of a super method is still executed by the inherited method. 
As it can be seen from the sub-method listed below, I commented `super()` to prevent the superclass code from being executed. 
This is the super-class:

```
class superClass(superClassOfSuperClass):
    def __init__(self, data):
        #[...]

        #unique call of the superMethod
        self.component.addActionListener(self.superMethod)

        #[...]

    def superMethod(self, param):
        print "I'm executed, but I don't have to be executed!"
```

This is the sub-method:

```
class subClass(superClass):
    def __init__(self, data, newData):
        superClass.__init__(self, data)
        self.newData = newData

        #[...]

    def superMethod(self, param):
        #super(superClass, self).superMethod(None)
        print 'only I have to be printed!!!'
```

The code works.
But I don't want to see the `superMethod` print.
Is there a way to prevent superMethod from running and make the subMethod execute only?
Because up to now I can see both print outputs.
I hope it's my shortcoming on OOP.

PS: I'm working with Jython 2.7 as you can see from tags.

Comment: What does your call site look like? btw `superMethod` and `subMethod` are different names and would not normally override one another..

Comment: Corrected. The call is actually made in the superclass. Is that the reason? Should I rewrite the `__init__` of the subclass?

Comment: What is your call site like?

Comment: is the `__ init__` of the superclass. I call it that:
`self.component.addActionListener(self.superMethod)` 

This is the only site where I call the superMethod

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. Please update the question with this new information.In fact please show both `__init__` methods.

Comment: So you're seeing *both* `superClass.superMethod` *and* `subClass.superMethod` being executed…?!

Comment: Done. Much stuff is superfluous. I kept only the essentials.

Comment: Yes @deceze! That's the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be another explanation, for instance if there are more classes involved and there is another class which inherits from `superClass`, but does not override `superMethod`.

The following code (I'm using python 3) shows that everything should work just fine:

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self, listener):
        listener.append(self.superMethod)

    def superMethod(self, param):
        print("I'm executed, but I don't have to be executed!")


class Sub(Super):
    def superMethod(self, param):
        print('Only me!')

methods = []
s = Sub(methods)

for method in methods:
    method(None)
```

Output:

```
Only me!
```

Comment: I believe you are calling a method out of classes. What I'm trying to do is override a method that's already assigned in the superclass (which is something I've done before). I will try to remove the old method, and put the new one by calling it in another way...

Comment: I've asked you about the call site and you haven't provided one, so in my question I had to make one of my own. Neither of our super classes call any of their own methods in their `__init__` methods

Comment: Of course, it's not called, I never call it directly (eg: `self.method(None)`), but it's a listener. It is activated only at the user's action on the UI. Despite this, it does not completely override.

Comment: Well, the UI will do the calling like I've simulated in my answer. It works ok in Python 3. Perhaps there is something in Jython 2.7 which works differently. Perhaps you could try my code in Jython.

Comment: Your solution is right. I saw those outputs because they were called by other objects, not by the object in question... stupid me! However, this gave me the chance to file the best I wanted my code, learning new things too! :)